# Get latitude/longitude from address without googles geolocation

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, user-input

Hi I am trying to create a store locator without using googles API or geolocation but I have hit a problem, I want the user to input there address or where they will be and then get the users location from that and then convert it into latitude and longitude.

The reason I am not using googles API or geolocation is because in their terms it says you have to have the map on the screen and this is not what I want, any help would be much appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 credit for abiding by the Google Ts&Cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From user side you request to enter zip code and on the basis of zip code you can find out the latitude and longitude.

There are so many sites which are selling the zip code database with the latitude and longitude information.

you may need to purchase and work on that.

on the basis of latitude and longitude you can find the distance between to zip codes.

Comment: i have got the code for the working out the distance between two points and i have got the location script working as well to automatically find where the user is i just wanted to now how to determine where the user was when they input there own location for example by address or post code

Comment: you can only determine through the zip code enter by the user. as no matter user is searching it from any where. but it matter what is the input he provides

Comment: any ideas how it can be done finding the person location from the post code and then converting that to lat/lon without having to pay for

Comment: you need the dot net code for distance calculating on the basis of zipcode.

Comment: i have the code to calculate between two distances what i need is the code to take the users input from a form and then process this into latitude and longitude so that i can perform the function with the distance calculation code.